# Listen for documents just when actually added to collection - swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection on Firestore and I listen for changes like this:

```
    func createMatchesListener(){

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    
    matchesListener = db.collection("Matches").document(currentUid).collection("Matches").addSnapshotListener({ snapshot, error in
        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
            if change.type == .added{
                
               // do things
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I only want to listen for documents that are actually **added** to that collection.
In fact, the problem is that whenever I invoke this function I receive **all** the documents of the collection as added documents and then I also receive documents added later.

How can I listen just for actually added later documents, ignoring the ones already present in the collection? Searching online I didn't find any solution to this issue.

EDIT:
This is the way I tried to solve the problem:

```
func createMatchesListener(){
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    
    getUidsAlreadyMade { uidsAlreadyMade in
        matchesListener = db.collection("Matches").document(currentUid).collection("Matches").addSnapshotListener({ snapshot, error in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                if change.type == .added{
                    let data = change.document.data()
                    let userId = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    if uidsAlreadyMade.contains(userId) == false{
                        //means the uid is newly created in the collection, do stuff accordingly
                        
                        
                        arrayOfUidsAlreadyMade.append(currentUid)
                    }
                }
                if change.type == .removed{
                   // if the document has been removed, remove also the id from the array of uids

                    let data = change.document.data()
                    let currentUid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                    arrayOfUidsAlreadyMade.removeAll { $0 == currentUid }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    
}

func getUidsAlreadyMade(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void){
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    db.collection("Matches").document(currentUid).collection("Matches").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        arrayOfUidsAlreadyMade.removeAll()
        
        snapshot?.documents.forEach({ doc in
            let dict = doc.data()
            let userId = dict["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            arrayOfUidsAlreadyMade.append(userId)
        })
        
        completion(arrayOfUidsAlreadyMade)
    }
}
```

Comment: What you describe is how it's supposed to work. From the docs *An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately* and then *Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot*. From there you have as fine-grained control as you need; for example you can use `if (diff.type == .added)` to only handle additive changes. If that doesn't address the question, please clarify the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for the answer, what do you mean by "diff"? 
the problem is that I don't want what you call "document snapshot immediately" but only the successive write operations to that collection.
I think the best workaround is to get an initial state of the collection, and then whenever a new change.type == .added , compare that document with the list of documents already present in the collection

Comment: You should really read the documentation! Getting started guide [Listen For Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). What you're stating is exactly how Firebase works - when you use `addSnapshotListener` it will get the initial state of the collection and then notify you of changes thereafter. The `diff` is a var that provides a granular level of control for what events you want to handle - .added for example. See the docs [Changes Between Snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Comment: I understand that this is how Firestore works, I was wondering if It was possible to get only documents when they are actually added to the collection and NOT the first snapshot of documents already there. @Jay

Comment: You had said *get an initial state of the collection* in your above comment so that kind of lead to me saying *addSnapshotListener* would work as it gets the initial state and then notifies the app of changes like a document being added.

Comment: I understand what you are after but the core answer is that if you only want to *ever* know about added documents, you would need to handle that in code. e.g. have a `addedDocuments` collection that will only ever contain 1 document and you have a listener on that collection. When a document is added, you will receive a notification of that event along with the added document. You'll then need to delete that document from  the `addedDocuments` collection and then store that document in a separate collection which does not have a listener on it.

Comment: No, I don't want the initial state of the collection, that's the main purpose of this topic.
I need to ignore the documents present in the collection and only get the ones that are added in real-time.
P.S. your second option makes sense, but It seems a little bit laborious to adoperate

Comment: In that case there are "no options". If you want to be notified of changes, you must add an observer and therefore will be provided the initial state of the collection being observed. My second option will really be the only option and it's pretty straightforward and easy to implement. That being said, you could store documentId's in a local SQL database or maybe plist as well as in Firestore but that's going to get really cumbersome trying to keep everything in sync. It may just be best to use the built in functionality - it's incredibly fast and highly reliable.

Comment: I just had a use case for something similar so I added an answer that is working for us.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to include a timestamp in your Firestore documents.

Suppose your documents store Tasks, for example

```
documentId
   task: "get dinner"
   timestamp: 20211123
```

and suppose your app doesn't care about past tasks, only new ones.

When the tasks are read, update the timestamp as to when that occurred.

Then each time after that you want to read only 'new data' specify that in your listener, keeping track of when the last read timestamp was:

```
db.collection("task").whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThan: lastReadTimeStamp).addSnapshotListener...
```

The above will only read in tasks that occured after the prior timestamp and add a Listener (reading in all of the new tasks so you can populate the UI).

Answer (score 1):

You can store an array with the ID of the documents that you already have stored in the device. That way, all that you need to do before doing things is checking that document's id is not in your array

Comment: makes sense, I thought there was an easier workaround offered by Firestore but, as always, there is not

Comment: @StackGU I am not sure how this answer would work. To get the ID of the documents already stored, you would have to read them all in to start with, right? And if you're going to do that you'll use `addSnapshotListener` so you're back to square one.

Comment: Actually, I think it may be a great Idea, 
1) I get all the ids of the documents in the collection using getDocuments function (which only return ones).
2) I store the uids in a separate array
3) in the snapshot listener cited before, I check wheter the .added documents IDs are different to the ones in the previous array, if so I actually know that these documents are fresh and just added to the collection.
Please @Jay If you think this solution might not work, let me know that we'll find a solution

Comment: @StackGU 1) is not a solution as [getDocuments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) returns all of the documents in the collection with all of the child data so it essentially does the same thing as `addSnapshotListener` but is a one shot (e.g.  doesn't leave a listener)

Comment: I don't know if you understood what I was trying to do here, the getDocuments function serves just as a way of capturing the collection as is, knowing which doc IDs are already present in the collection.
Then I also add the snapshot listener (as we know returns the collection documents already present AND eventually new elements that are added), so that we can exclude the diff == .added documents of the listener from the ones that we "captured" from getDocuments at the beginning. 
What is wrong with this approach? For completeness I add the snipped of code I have created

Comment: @StackGU I understand what you are trying to do but please read the documentation! `getDocuments` *returns all of the documents*, so does `addSnapshotListener`. If you're using getDocuments to get the documentId's and then add a listener, all of the documents are read TWICE 1) getDocuments reads all documents 2) addSnapshotListener reads all documents and leaves a listener. Using addSnapshotListener will read them once, and leave a lister. 2x as fast and 1/2 the cost. This answer suggests storing an array and that means you have to read the data at some point to populate the array, right?

Comment: I listened to your suggestion of populating a collection with only one document (the one that we want to listen for) and deleting it when it has been read, and I will say it's working fine till now

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of preventing Firestore from returning the initial snapshot of documents when a document listener is added, so just use a boolean to keep track of the initial snapshot and ignore it.

```
var listenerDidInit = false

func createMatchesListener(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    
    matchesListener = db.collection("Matches").document(currentUid).collection("Matches").addSnapshotListener({ snapshot, error in
        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        if listenerDidInit {
            snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                if change.type == .added{
                    // do things
                }
            })
        } else {
            listenerDidInit = true
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private var listener: ListenerRegistration?


self.listener = db.collection("Matches") // matchesListener


listener!.remove()
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_